# how to filter selected objects then hide objects not selected

Tags: jquery, filtering

following up from yesterday...

This portion of the code does work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#listMenu a').click(function (selected) {
        var getPage = $(this).attr('id');
        var getName = $(this).attr('name');

        //console.log(getPage);
        //console.log(getName);

            $(function() {
            $("#" + getName ).show();
            var getColor = $('#' + getName ).css('background-color');
            $('#header' ).css('background', getColor);
            $('#slideshow' ).css('background', getColor);
            $('span').css('background', getColor);
            $('#menuContainer').css('background', getColor);

        });

        $('li.listMenu ul').hide();
  });           
});
```

I am able to get what I wanted selected; based on vars getPage and
getName, now I need to hide what is not selected.

I have tried this:

```
$(function() {
  var notSelected = $('div').filter(selected).attr('id', 'name');
  $(this).hide();
  console.log(notSelected);
});
```

placed just above: `$('li.listMenu ul').hide();`

but it's not correct, remember I am really a newbie.

what I see on screen is the new selected items on top of what should be hidden.

again any help is appreciated.

-sjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want this if you're clicking a `<a>` inside a div:

```
$('div').not($(this).closest('div')).hide();
```

Or if you meant to fade out the other `<a>` elements:

```
$('#listMenu a').not(this).hide();
```

The [.not() function](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filters those elements matching out of the set, so `.hide()` will run on the rest of the elements.  In your case `selected` is the click event, what you want is `this` which refers to the `#listMenu a` that the click is coming from.